# Programmatically login by user

Tags: magento-1.9

```
<?php
    require_once "app/Mage.php";
    Mage::app('default');
    umask(0);
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));

    $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

$session->start();

            if (!empty($email) && !empty($password )) {
                    try {
                        $session->login($email, $password );
                        if ($session->getCustomer()->getIsJustConfirmed()) {
                            $this->_welcomeCustomer($session->getCustomer(), true);
                        }
                    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                        switch ($e->getCode()) {
                            case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_NOT_CONFIRMED:
                                $value = Mage::helper('customer')->getEmailConfirmationUrl($email);
                                $message = Mage::helper('customer')->__('This account is not confirmed. <a href="%s">Click here</a> to resend confirmation email.', $value);
                                break;
                            case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD:
                                $message = $e->getMessage();
                                break;
                            default:
                                $message = $e->getMessage();
                        }
                        $session->addError($message);
                        $session->setUsername($email);
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        // Mage::logException($e); // PA DSS violation: this exception log can disclose customer password
                    }
                } else {
                    $session->addError('Login and password are required.');


   }
?>
```

I am trying to programmatically login,it is successful but in product details page I get an error like this:

> WHOOPS, OUR BAD... The page you requested was not found, and we have a
>   fine guess why. If you typed the URL directly, please make sure the
>   spelling is correct. If you clicked on a link to get here, the link is
>   outdated.

Answer (score 3):

I have created an Observer:

> event name: `controller_action_predispatch`

**And created an observer:**

```
class Company_Module_Model_Customer_Observer {

    public function requireLogin($observer) {        
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
        $controllerAction = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction();
        $data = $controllerAction->getRequest()->getParams();
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
        $email = $data['username']; // or your user Id
        $password = $data['password']; // or your user Password
        $session->login($email, $password);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also face same problem after user login.

Finally , I resolved it by overriding the **Mage_Reports_Model_Event_Observer** method: public function **catalogProductView**(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) and added a **return true**;.

you just have to modify the config.xml file of your extension like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyNamespace_MyModule>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MyNamespace_MyModule>
    </modules>
    <frontend> <!-- Be careful to use <frontend> like above, <global> would not work -->
        <events>
            <catalog_controller_product_view>
                <observers>
                    <reports>
                        <class>MyNamespace_MyModule_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>catalogProductView</method>
                    </reports>
                </observers>
            </catalog_controller_product_view>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

And it worked !!

Comment: Its working for me.Is there any issue if this method always return true.